# What are the passwords for the hidden missions in commandos?

Tags: commandos

I've completed all 20 missions in commandos (the first one). I once typed a random password for fun which took me to a hidden mission. There you had to rescue someone from some kind of prison. It wasn't on the original missions & I couldn't get it back cause I don't remember the password.

Comment: Does the list [seen here](http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/cbel.html) look right?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're were looking for? These are for Commandos: Behind Enemy Lines.

Level  Password

Norway:

LEVEL  PASSWORD   MISSION OBJECTIVE

2      NS2B7      Destroy river base.

3      BFQBF      Destroy dam.

4      YGF1J      Destroy headquarters.

5      JJTCG      Destroy radar site.

6      NT1WN      Destroy rail cannon.

7      Y3YWX      Destroy U-Boats.

North Africa:

LEVEL  PASSWORD   MISSION OBJECTIVE

8      B3WJO      Destroy fuel depot.

9      HIAXT      Destroy desert compound.

10     G4CM3      Rescue pilot.

11     GDODW      Destroy oil refinery.

12     5MB4M      Rescue prisoner and escape.

Normandy:

LEVEL  PASSWORD   MISSION OBJECTIVE

13     65UWX      Destroy battleship.

14     CT34V      Secure beachhead.

15     YN9PD      Assassinate general.

Germany:

LEVEL  PASSWORD   MISSION OBJECTIVE

16     BY4MD      Defend bridge.

17     Y14PW      Rescue resistance member.

18     8POJ8      Destroy bridge.

19     8WGJ0      Destroy V2 rockets.

20     88U4V      Destroy doomsday compound

If those do not work try the following:

2      4JJXB

3      ZDD1T

4      RFF1J

5      K4TCG

6      MIR4M

7      7QVJV

8      K99XC

9      AAAX1

10     JSGPW

11     CMODD

12     JGHD3

13     PUUWW

14     WT348

15     139P0

16     L9IPV

17     5LIMV

18     YJOJG

19     YFCWJ

20     GDKWT